# Help Me Identify This Brick / Bracket

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I'm trying to recreate the building in the picture (*Berghain by Matteo Plateroti*), but I'm having trouble finding what bricks, tiles, or brackets were used at the bottom layer with white stripes.

I assume those are 1x2 tiles at the front but what are they attached to? [image]

Close-up (cut from [a larger resolution image](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4c/c8/66/4cc866704243a2b2780a5be5a2303030.jpg)): [image]

Answer (score 16):

Picture little blurry, but this is what I see...  The builder attached the tiles to [*Part Number Forty-Seventy*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4070&name=Brick,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Headlight&category=%5BBrick,%20Modified%5D#T=C&C=1).

*[Part #4864a](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=49240#T=C&C=13)*, the (black) window piece is really *trans-black* in color, but the way it's used here, with it being reversed and all, obstructs the proper identity of the white 1x1 bricks, causing some viewing tricks on the eyes...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Bricks.SE! The picture is a bit of an eye-chart, but upon zooming in you can see that the white lines (and the grey lines in other pillars) are half a plate high. This means they are likely the vertical part of a [white 99780 Bracket 1x2 - 1x2 Inverted](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=109305#T=S&C=1&O=%7B%22color%22:%221%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) or [99207 Bracket 1x2 - 2x2 Inverted](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99207&name=Bracket%201%20x%202%20-%202%20x%202%20Inverted&category=%5BBracket%5D#T=S&C=1&O=%7B%22color%22:%221%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D), placed vertically facing down against the back structure of the building.

[image]
[image]